# Remove extra route value after route matching

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to remove some of route values after route was matched but before matched action is executed. My action doesn't contain some of route values and I want to remove them.

In other words, there is some route value which won't be used in my controller (but is used by filters) and I don't want to keep it at action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found an easy solution - define custom RouteHandler:

```
public class CustomMvcRouteHandler: MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override System.Web.IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        requestContext.RouteData.Values.Remove("someValue");
        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}

// ... and when defining the route, set the route handler to be your custom route handler
route.RouteHandler = new CustomMvcRouteHandler();
```

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere you can get a hold of the `RouteData` for the request you can get call:

```
RouteData.Values.Remove("keyNameOfParameterToRemove");
```

But this comes with no promise of doing what you want it to do, unless you can expand on why you want to do this so I can test that specific goal.

Comment: The question was not how to remove value but where